# AWS EC2 SSH Could not resolve hostname nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: amazon-ec2

Yes, there have been many postings for many years with this issue.  Their solutions haven't worked for me.

I was having no trouble SSHing into my ec2 instance from my Mac terminal until I setup Elastic IP and Cloudfront.  That went well and the original IP for the instance has been replaced and it is serving the Web pages for my domain.

I thought all I had to do for the new IP was to change the Public DNS in the SSH string to the new one.  Then I get the error.  If I use the old one I get the same error.  There is no DNS issues because the site has been working for days. Also, in Webstorm I made the change to the host in the deployment preferences and I can SFTP into the instance without a problem with the same .pem file as before.

```
ssh -i "path/to/ubuntu.pem" ubuntu@ec2-xx.xx.xxx.xxx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

The part after the @ sign is a copy from my ec2 instance.

So the question is, what changed when I moved to Cloudfront and Elastic IP besides the IP?  Why is this only affecting SSH and not SFTP?  Why did the routine login become a nightmare to solve?

Comment: Does it work if you use the elastic IP address instead of public DNS in your ssh command?

Comment: Right. In the EC2 instance the public DNS address changed to the Elastic IP and I just replaced the old one with that.  I really don't understand how that could break SSH.  I've rebooted the instance.  I've rebooted Webstorm.  This morning I'm going to go back to the old Windows habit of rebooting my Mac in desperation :-)

Comment: I rebooted my computer, I'm sure this wouldn't be the problem, and I disabled Cloudfront and no help.

Answer (score 4):

Not an elegant solution but I put my pem key into home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys and can log in with the Elastic IP:

`ssh -i "path/to/ubuntu.pem" ubuntu@xx.xx.xxx.xxx`

I still can't log in with the original string:

`ubuntu@ec2-xx.xx.xxx.xxx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`

I would like to know why and how.

Answer (score 0):

It might be happened due to an incorrect command for ssh. And might be due to you are trying to access ssh from a different folder where .pem file not located

Answer (score 0):

What works for me: SSH from MacOS to AWS EC2:

I added an entry to ~.ssh/config, copying the `Public IPv4 address` and `Public IPv4 DNS` from the EC2 instance details in the AWS portal

```
Host <Public IPv4 address>
        Hostname <Public IPv4 DNS>
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<keypair filename>.pem
        IdentitiesOnly yes
```

I could then

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/<keypair filename>.pem ec2-user@<Public IPv4 address>
```